# Buffer with parallel capacitors

Tags: amplifier, audio, inverter, buffer, summing

Hello I am trying to build the following 3 band equalizer for a project.
As I am analyzing the circuit I've come to a problem.
I do understand what the "second stage" does: It's a summing amp that regulates Bass, Mid and treble gain with each potentiometer. Quite simple.

However, I cannot understand what the "first stage" does. I would have guessed that it is an unit inverting op amp since R1 = R3 but both the C1 capacitor and the parallel impedance C2 || R2 got me very confused. What does this stage really do? Why I need the C2 || R2 impedance? It is the first time that I see that the other terminal of the ideal op amp is not shorted to ground.

I am sorry if this is a rookie question I am very new to electronics!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This ensures the source to the 2nd stage is a voltage source  and not some unknown impedance like a 10k line signal that would affect the filters. Normally one balances R2//R2=R2 to null the effects of input current in bipolar Op Amps. normally done if R>=100k. or if very low offset voltage was needed.

C2 is useless as there is no HF noise suppression.

U2 ought to have the same balanced R on Vin+ if input bias current was an issue in U1 and both are unity gain, so almost a non-issue
with 10k values. But beware of Iin , and offset Vio & Iio when using high resistor values so as to NOT use Vin+= directly to gnd.

e.g. When there is input bias current **say 1uA** and 1M with a gain of 10 then output offset = 10Vdc but here with a 5K error for U1 balanced Req , the DC offset might be 1uA * 5k * Av=1 = **5 mV**

Conclusion: rookie design.